# how to get last month order item sales report in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to get last month order items report. Here is my table structure

```
orders
    id - integer
    amount- double

order_items (pivot table)
    id - integer
    order_id - foreign
    item_id - foreign
    quantity
    price
```

Here is my `Item` model

```php
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_items', 'item_id',  'order_id')
                ->withPivot('quantity', 'price');
}
```

Here is my `Order` model

```php
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'order_items', 'order_id', 'item_id')
                ->withPivot('quantity', 'price')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Here is my controller where I got last month's all orders

```php
$orders = Order::with('items')
               ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month)
               ->get();
```

After foreach loop in blade,

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
  <ul>
    @foreach($order->items as $item)
      <li>
        {{ $item->name }}, {{ $item->pivot->quantity }}, {{ $item->pivot->price }}
      </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

I'm getting data like this

```
Item Name  Quantity Price
Item A         20    600
Item A          5    100
Item A          7    200
Item B          2     20
Item B          8     100
Item C        100    1000
```

But I don't want to show same item in this row, I want to show like this

```
Item Name  Quantity Price
Item A         32    900
Item B         10    120
Item C        100    1000
```

How to sum quantity and price if item is same?

Answer (score 0):

the order_items information is the pivot table. You just have to loop over your orders and then over each order's items.

```xml
@foreach ($orders as $order)
  <p>{{ $order->id }}, {{ $order->amount }}</p>
  <ul>
    @foreach($order->items as $item)
      <li>
        {{ $item->name }}, {{ $item->pivot->quantity }}, {{ $item->pivot->price }}
      </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: In this way Item will be repeated but I want Item will be unique .If order 1 has Item A and order 2 has also Item A then I want to show Item A only once and quantity and price will sum with the old one.